# Setting `Content-Disposition` on Object uploaded to S3?

Tags: c#, amazon-s3

I have a .NET Core project that uploads objects to an S3 bucket. I want to set the `Content-Disposition` so when the object is downloaded the name is what we want to be. (Not necessarily relevant, but I don't want to change the name of the object as the "download name" I am after is not guaranteed to be unique within the bucket).

This is what I am trying:

```
var fileTransferUtilityRequest = new TransferUtilityUploadRequest
{
    BucketName = "my-bucket", 
    FilePath = "/tmp/54a0f73d-65ea-4719-8227-b67209c15c9f.zip",
    PartSize = 6291456, // 6 MB.
    Key = "54a0f73d-65ea-4719-8227-b67209c15c9f.zip"
};

fileTransferUtilityRequest.Metadata.Add("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=\"human-name.zip\"");

await transferUtility.UploadAsync(fileTransferUtilityRequest, cancellationToken);
```

What it ends up doing is adding meta-data to the object with the key `x-amz-meta-content-disposition` and the value I set via code.

**Is there a way to set the `Content-Disposition` key during upload that I am missing?**

Comment: The optional user-defined metadata names must begin with "x-amz-meta-" it helps distinguish them from other HTTP headers. So it looks like it's concatenating `x-amz-meta-` (required name) and `content-disposition` (key name). I would [read](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/UsingMetadata.html) up on this in the documents.

Comment: Yes, but using the aws-console you can set several non-user defined Metadata values including Content-Dispositon. Also it can be done with SDKs for other languages. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/40719334/3340

Comment: I understand, I know you can set values (but not change key behaviour). What I am trying to say is you can't change this behaviour at all; it's defined in the specs. `User-defined metadata must begin with the prefix "x-amz-meta-", otherwise Amazon S3 will not set the key value pair as you define it. You define custom metadata by adding a name that you choose to the x-amz-meta- key. This creates a custom key.`

Comment: `For example, if you add the custom name alt-name, the metadata key would be x-amz-meta-alt-name.` this is [right](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/user-guide/add-object-metadata.html) in the docs.

Comment: I guess I disagree on the stance that `Content-Disposition` is not custom metadata. It is a standard header, that they support via the web console, and you can set there manually. We can argue about where the Metadata collection in this class is just meant for `Custom` items or not, but there should still be a way to set the this non-custom stock header via the sdk, as it can be done via the api as seen in the node question I linked.

Comment: It is clear after looking at the sdk code in github, that what you say is how it is treated there though (https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-net/blob/966617d346169e89a693dae74c5eec5cda0551b2/sdk/src/Services/S3/Custom/Model/MetadataCollection.cs). I guess I was just hoping they had a property like they do for Content-Type that you can set and have it pass through.

Comment: I would agree having a property would be nice, but unfortunately it's a no go for now. Also the API you linked is for JavaScript, not .Net; the libraries are different. In this case, implementations may not be the same and or available across their SDK's...

Comment: Opened an issue on GIhub, so maybe one day (https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-net/issues/1481)

Comment: I would have mentioned the pre-appending of `x-amz-meta` as well... just a thought so they might understand a bit more and or link to this post?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can set the `ContentDisposition` in the Headers of the `TransferUtilityUploadRequest`

```
var fileTransferUtilityRequest = new TransferUtilityUploadRequest
{
    BucketName = "my-bucket", 
    FilePath = "/tmp/54a0f73d-65ea-4719-8227-b67209c15c9f.zip",
    PartSize = 6291456, // 6 MB.
    Key = "54a0f73d-65ea-4719-8227-b67209c15c9f.zip"
};

fileTransferUtilityRequest.Headers.ContentDisposition = "attachment; filename=file-name.pdf";
```